Zoomed fo:extenal graphic for better font size is blocking the table borders, how can I contain the image in assigned container limits
I am creating a report with table(s) containing text and images. I have formatted the report as below
Report
As shown in picture I have to insert the image in right section. This is a full page instructions and customer wanted to fit this in 1/3 of the page and for better font size I have to zoom the page. Now after zooming the external graphic is blocking the table border as highlighted in the picture. I used below XSL code. I want to restrict the image in allocated 410pts even after zooming, if the image edges are cut that is fine
Used below code. I also tried block container absolute positioning which is not zooming the image so that did not help. Also tried inserting another table that also did not help.
XSLT Code

Post your code as text, not as a screenshot.

I have posted question here first time and I had difficulty in formatting the code as per this webpage standards

StackOverflow supports Markdown and has clear instructions on the right-hand side of the question form.
